# How to disable remote assistance using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am trying to disable remote assistance through batch file. But following code is not working. Is there any problem with this command?

```
@echo off
@echo Disable remote assistance
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v "fAllowToGetHelp" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
pause
```

Comment: When I toggle the option in System Properties it is editing the key in: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance`

Comment: This is the sort of thing that should be done via [group policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456993.aspx) rather than hacking on undocumented registry keys.

Comment: Thanks HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I toggle the option in System Properties it is editing the key in: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance